# How to move data of request body from one route to another in Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

On my MERN application, I have two routes. One for 'Storing Data', let's call it 'data' route and another to 'Register User', so call it 'register' route.

When sending a request to 'data' route, the client might send 'username, password & name', because that is optional.

Now, if the client does send 'username, password & name'. how can I redirect those data from 'data' route to 'register' route, and then return a response back to the 'data' route and then store the data to database?

Individually, both the routes are working. I just don't know how to transfer certain data to one route to another.

This is Data route file:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { data, email, password, name } = req.body;
  

  if(email && password && name) {
    // Register User here
  }

  // code to store data to database will go here
  


});

module.exports = router;
```

This is Register Route file:

```js
router.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { email, password, name } = req.body;

  try {
    let user = await User.findOne({ email });

    if (user) {
      return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'User already exists' });
    }

    user = new User({
      name,
      email,
      password,
    });

    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);

    user.password = await bcrypt.hash(password, salt);

    await user.save();

  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err.message);
    res.status(500).json('Server Error');
  }
});

module.exports = router;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can chain your controllers together, just like you would do with middleware. Each controller is called with 3 arguments: request response and next; calling next invokes next controller in chain. Note that setting response ( e.g. `res.send()` ) AND calling next will result in error, so only set response once.

```
router
.route('/')
.post( 
  function register(req, res, next){ 
    if(!/* my completeness check */){ 
      return next()
    } else {
      res.send('done!')
    }
  },
  function store(req, res){
    
  })
```