# How to pass request body object to other routes?

Tags: node.js, express, request, middleware, body-parser

Anyone know the solution? When I console log the variable it shows undefined. I need to pass the req.body (name and email) element to second post route which is "/company" route. I have two forms and I want to pass the first form data to second form the "/company" route form. then the two form data will be stored in mongoDb. I tried everything but I got only undefined in second route the "/company" route

```
import express from "express";
const app = express();
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
 
//Assign the name and email to variable and sent to last route
const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body;
  let nameNew = name;
  let emailNew = email;
  // add nameNew and emailNew to req object
  // so that it can be access in other routes
  req.nameNew = nameNew;
  req.emailNew = emailNew;
  // console.log(nameNew);
  // console.log(emailNew);
  next();
};
 
//Get name email from user input and sent it middleware
app.post("/", middleware, (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body;
  res.send("Home route");
});
 
//Get the name and email from middleware
app.post("/company", middleware, (req, res) => {
  // console.log(nameNew);
 
  // access req.body without middleware
  // console.log(req.body);
 
  // access req.body using middleware
  console.log(req.nameNew);
  console.log(req.emailNew);
 
  res.send("Company route");
});
 
//Server running
app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started `);
});
```

Comment: You write `console.log(req.nameNew)`, did you mean `console.log(req.body.nameNew)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When your request gets into your `app.post("/")` it sets the `nameNew` variable inside your middleware scope. You cannot access this variable in your other routes.

If you want to access variables shared from your middleware you can use `res.locals` : https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.locals

You can't pass data from route 1 to route 2 through middleware.

It passes through the middleware and sets the variables but on your `res.send` theses variable will disappear. These are just set for the "instance" of the incoming request and on `res.send` will be destroyed.

You would need to send back data to the front-end to pass it back to your API for route 2.

You can call functions from your route definition :

```js
app.get('/getUserInfos', isLoggedIn, (req, res) => {
  return getUserInfos(res);
});
```

This way you can process your data and save it however you want.

Also, looks like you can chain functions there : https://stackoverflow.com/a/62723674/12343548

Comment: bro I made a little change in question. Can you please see that again. I want to get first route data to second route and then store to db.

Answer (score 0):

I use req.app.locals to send the data in first route to second route. Anyone want to do this type of program in future Here is the solution.

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const path = require("path");
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

const middleware = (req, res, next) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body;
  req.app.locals.nameNew = name;
  req.app.locals.emailNew = email;
  next();
};

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/index.html"));
});

app.post("/", middleware, (req, res) => {
  const { name, email } = req.body;
  res.send("Home Route");
});

app.get("/company", (req, res) => {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname + "/company.html"));
  console.log(req.app.locals.nameNew);
  console.log(req.app.locals.emailNew);
});

app.post("/company", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.app.locals.nameNew);
  console.log(req.app.locals.emailNew);
  res.send("Company Route");
});

//Server running
app.listen(4001, () => {
  console.log(`Server Started `);
});
```